# Android Studio Layout Rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I have a layout that I need to rotate, but still fill the entire screen. Using `android:rotation` and `match_parent` scales gives this result:

[image: current output]

Comment: Can you give your current code? Additionally, do you mean that the white area should cover the entire screen (and of course be partially off the screen)?

Comment: @JakeSteam I already found solution on RU forum, thanks.